# Putting Line Breaks in XQuery XML Source but NOT in Output

Tags: xml, xquery

For a piece of code im writing i require the output of the XQuery to be on a single line. However, the XML markup is incredibly verbose. This is not an issue for the output of the program because it does not require to be human readable, but the source code (for maintenance purposes) of course does need to be human readable. Is there a nice clean way to put line breaks in the XQuery XML that do not flow through to the output? I currently am using the work around below.

You can pretty much ignore the code but note that this will all output on to a single line when processed.  Notice the constant 'nl' being inserted whenever I want a line break in my source code.

```
let $nl := '';


 <type><name>void</name></type> <name>{fn:string($className)}__{fn:string($requestReceived/@name)}__received</name>{$nl
 }<parameter_list>(<param><decl><type><specifier>const</specifier> <name>{fn:replace($requestReceived/mt:input/@qtype,":","::")}</name> &amp;{$nl
 }</type><name>{fn:string($requestReceived/mt:input/@name)}</name></decl></param>,<param><decl><type><specifier>const</specifier> <name>{$nl
 }{fn:replace($requestReceived/mt:input/@qtype,":","::")}</name> &amp;</type><name>{fn:string($requestReceived/mt:output/@name)}</name></decl></param>)</parameter_list>;
```

Does anyone have a better alternative?

Comment: Usually there will be a serialization option for this. What XQuery engine are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in my question - I am using Zorba.

Answer (score 1):

Zorba supports XQuery 3.0 and the serialization options. The following should also be valid for all other XQuery 3.0 engines, I tested with both Zorba and BaseX.

### Disable Indentation

Setting `output:indent "no"` will disable newlines for each result.

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:indent "no";

<a><b/></a>
```

Result:

```
<a><b/></a>
```

### Disable Lines Breaks in-Between XML Snippets

If you don't return a single XML fragment, but a sequence of those, also set `output:item-separator ""` which will remove newlines in-between:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:indent "no";
declare option output:item-separator "";

(<a><b/></a>, <foo/>)
```

Result:

```
<a><b/></a><foo/>
```

Comment: Nice one! It was the item-separator serialization option i wasn't aware of and it did the trick! Much appreciated.

Comment: Ahhh sorry @jens I had to un-accept. I was mistaken. If i take out the '{$nl}' from my code then it puts the output  on separate lines again. Even with these serialization options in.

Comment: Well it seems you actually include the contents of `$nl`, so this is a string content (and not added by serialization). Remove it, or consider adding a `declare variable $nl := ´';` among the serialization options if you need to keep it for whatever reasons.

Comment: I do include the contents of `$nl` because this allows me to put a line break in my source code which is then included in the output only as the empty string. Now if i remove the `{$nl}` then it results in line breaks in my output, regardless of serialization option.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) for this problem?

Comment: I will do so ASAP, I've got a lot on for the remainder of the day. Ill try and get back later today or tomorrow!

Comment: Isn't your first example wrong? The query contains `<foo/>`, but the result does not. Besides (if my expectation is correct and your query is not supposed to contain `<foo/>`), declaring the option `item-separator` has no point in the first example and just add noise...

Comment: The mighty powers of copy/paste tricked me here. I started with the "large" example and realized the OP probably only needs a part of it, and obviously failed at properly replacing the query. Thank you for pointing this out.